# Printing all elements of graph one by one in python

Tags: python, graph-traversal

I  tried  to traverse a graph in this algorithm in python. What Changes should I 
   make if I want to print all elements of graph one by one or traversing the whole 
   graph.

Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks.

```
       grapth={'A': ['B', 10, 'B', 10, 'B', 10, 'C', 15], 'C': [1001, 'OUT'], 'B':   
       [1000, 'IN', 1000, 'IN']}

       print "Path:",find_all_paths(Portdict1,'A','IN')



 def find_all_paths(graph, start, end, path=[]):
    path = path + [start]
    if start == end:
        return [path]
    if not graph.has_key(start):
        return []
    paths = []
    for node in graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            newpaths = find_all_paths(graph, node, end, path)
            for newpath in newpaths:
                paths.append(newpath)
    return paths
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "Graph" is a dictionary, dictionaries in Python are unordered, if you want to use an [ordered dictionary](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), you can import it from the [`collections`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571438/test-case-execution-order-in-pytest) module.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

graph = OrderedDict({'A': ['B', 10, 'B', 10, 'B', 10, 'C', 15], 'C': [1001, 'OUT'], 'B': [1000, 'IN', 1000, 'IN']})
```

Proof that it is ordered:

```
>>> for key, value in graph.items():
    print key, value


A ['B', 10, 'B', 10, 'B', 10, 'C', 15]
C [1001, 'OUT']
B [1000, 'IN', 1000, 'IN']
```

Notice, that since your initial code has the keys in the order "A, C, B" that is the order they will stay in with the OrderedDict.