# Py.test fixture: Use function fixture in scope fixture

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, pytest, fixtures

I am facing a small issue with pytest fixtures, would appreciate your help.

I have a few function fixtures as mentioned below. for simplicity I have not show the implementation.

```
@pytest.fixture()
def get_driver():
    pass

@pytest.fixture()
def login(get_driver):
    pass

@pytest.fixture()
def settings(login):
    pass
```

the problem is I need one more (**session level**) fixture which does the setup before I run my first test case. (actually start testing). i.e. go to settings page and create few settings. (after login)

now the problem is I can't do like this using **session level fixture**, as I can't use function level fixture in session level. **or can I?**

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def setup(settings):
    settings.create_settings()
    pass
```

Comment: Documentation says 'no'. Function level fixture can use session level ones but not the other way around. I guess you need to add more details to your situation so we might be able to figure a workaround to your problem.

Comment: the problem is i need one more fixture which is called only once before first test case. (session or module). however the problem is, i can't use `settings` fixture which has all the function related to creating `data for test` in this fixture.

Comment: Your `get_driver` is a function level fixture, does it mean you are creating a new instance of the `driver` for every test function? Or you're just retrieving the same `driver` instance that you will use in your session scope `setup` fixture?

Comment: I am creating new driver instance for each test.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use a workaround. The action needs to be done in a `function` scoped fixture with `autouse` set to `True`.

You need to initialize a variable in `session` based fixture, which will check if the `settings` have been done or not. If not done, then you will do the settings and change the flag to `False`

Below is a working example

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def settings_page():
    config = {"config_done": False}
    return config


@pytest.fixture()
def init(request):
    print("init called")
    return "init"


@pytest.fixture()
def driver():
    print("driver called")

    return "driver"


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def init_settings(settings_page, driver):
    if not settings_page["config_done"]:
        print("Settings being done only the first time")
        settings_page["config_done"] = True


@pytest.fixture()
def login():
    print("login called")
    return "login"


@pytest.fixture()
def logged_in_driver(init, driver, login):
    print("logged in driver is ready")
    return (init, driver, login)


@pytest.fixture()
def non_logged_in_driver(init, driver):
    print("non logged in driver is ready")
    return (init, driver)


def test_1(logged_in_driver):
    print("test_1")


def test_2(non_logged_in_driver):
    print("test_2")
```

Output is as below

```
test.py driver called
Settings being done only the first time
init called
login called
logged in driver is ready
.test_1
driver called
init called
non logged in driver is ready
.test_2
```

So you can see settings only happens once

Comment: this is what I am currently doing, the over head is for every test it checks if setting is done or not. I was thinking if there is any other better way to do this

Comment: You think checking a true or false is an overhead? It might add few ms in total to your whole suite and those should not matter

Answer (score 1):

This workaround tries to achieve the same result without creating a session level fixture. It answers your need for a setting that is `called only once before first test case` as you mentioned in your comment above.

Create a `conftest.py` and place the following contents:

```
import pytest


def pytest_sessionstart(session):
    print("Initialising Session Level Settings")
    login = "A specialized login"
    settings(login).create_settings()


@pytest.fixture()
def get_driver():
    print("Get Driver")


@pytest.fixture()
def login(get_driver):
    print("Login")


@pytest.fixture()
def settings(login):
    print("Settings")

    class Setter:
        def create_settings(self):
            print("[Success] Settings created!")
    return Setter()
```

You can then use this in your test like below:

```
def test_one(settings):
    print("Test one...")


def test_two(settings):
    print("Test two...")
```

Executing the test should give an effect close to what you wanted (based on what I can infer from your given information so far).

```
(py362) D:\repo\git\ens_qa>py.test -sv stackoverflow\ScopeWorkaroundTests.py
Initialising Session Level Settings
Settings
[Success] Settings created!
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.6.2, pytest-3.2.1, py-1.4.34, pluggy-0.4.0 -- d:\virtualenv\py362\scripts\python.exe
cachedir: .cache
rootdir: D:\repo\git\ens_qa, inifile:
collected 2 items

stackoverflow/ScopeWorkaroundTests.py::test_one Get Driver
Login
Settings
Test one...
PASSED
stackoverflow/ScopeWorkaroundTests.py::test_two Get Driver
Login
Settings
Test two...
PASSED

========================== 2 passed in 0.05 seconds ===========================

(py362) D:\repo\git\ens_qa>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do it, is to add some flag and use autouse like below:

```
import pytest

flag = True

@pytest.fixture()
def get_driver():
    pass

@pytest.fixture()
def login(get_driver):
    pass

@pytest.fixture()
def settings(login):
    pass

@pytest.fixture(autouse = True)
def setup(settings):
    global flag
    if flag:
        settings.create_settings()
        flag = False
    pass
```