# Can pytest run a test iff another fails?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a situation where I can do a very fast validation check on an entire object, and if that check passes the object is guaranteed to be healthy.  If it fails, I need to identify the aspects that are problematic using time intensive checks.

I was hoping for something like:
"@pytest.mark.dependency(depends=["test_a"])" except instead of only running on success it would only run on a failure.

Comment: I don't think `pytest` supports something like this. Is there an issue with just using an `if` statement and running another test if your assertion fails?

Comment: I'm mostly asking in search of best practices.

Comment: Can you explain your "intensive checks" more detailed? You would usually run the failing test alone with a debugger on or similar.

Comment: I've seen something similar to this, and as I recall we just used an `if` statement. I think this case comes up extraordinarily rarely, so I think a one off `if` is apropos. If you find it happens a lot in your API, you could write a decorator that works like you hope

Comment: @KlausD.
This has come up for database validations (checking the hash of a table is easy, checking the hash of each row / column is costly) and for image validations (comparing a single screenshot vs comparing each element cropped and isolated).

Comment: You are looking for [`pytest-dependency`](https://pytest-dependency.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html).

Comment: @hoefling
I actually took a look at that before posting this, it only works for the opposite case (run test b only if test a succeeds), right?

If not, could you provide an example of a "run only if test a fails"?

Comment: You're right, my bad! Didn't read your question through enough. Let me dig deeper, then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you pointed out correctly, `pytest-dependency` is unable to handle your case because it skips tests on failure and not on success. However, with some customizing of this plugin, you can get the desired result. Example:

```
# conftest.py

import pytest
from pytest_dependency import DependencyManager


def pytest_collection_modifyitems(session, config, items):
    modules = (item.getparent(pytest.Module) for item in items)
    marked_modules = {m for m in modules if m.get_closest_marker('depend_on_failures')}
    for module in marked_modules:
        module.dependencyManager = FailureDepManager()


class FailureDepManager(DependencyManager):

    def checkDepend(self, depends, item):
        for i in depends:
            if i in self.results:
                if self.results[i].isSuccess():
                    pytest.skip('%s depends on failures in %s' % (item.name, i))
                    break
```

`FailureDepManager` is the custom version of `pytest-dependency`'s `DependencyManager` that will skip dependent tests only when the dependency succeeds (has result `passed` or `XPASS`). Sadly, this behaviour can only be triggered on a per-module basis as this a current limitation of the plugin (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671567) for more details on that). Example usage:

```
import pytest

pytestmark = pytest.mark.depend_on_failures


@pytest.mark.dependency()
@pytest.mark.xfail(reason='simulate failing test')
def test_foo():
    assert False


@pytest.mark.dependency(depends=['test_foo'])
def test_bar():
    assert True
```

Due to the mark `depend_on_failures` on module level, `test_bar` will now run if `test_foo` fails:

```
================================== test session starts ==================================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.0, pytest-4.0.1, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.0
...
plugins: dependency-0.3.2
collected 2 items                                                                           

test_spam.py::test_foo xfail
test_spam.py::test_bar PASSED

========================== 1 passed, 1 xfailed in 0.08 seconds ==========================
```