# pytest skip everything if one test fails

Tags: python, pytest

What is best way to skip every remaining test if a specific test fails, here test_002_wips_online.py failed, and then there is no point in running further:

```
tests/test_001_springboot_monitor.py::TestClass::test_service_monitor[TEST12] PASSED [  2%]
tests/test_002_wips_online.py::TestClass::test01_online[TEST12] FAILED   [  4%]
tests/test_003_idpro_test_api.py::TestClass::test01_testapi_present[TEST12] PASSED [  6%]
```

I like to skip all remaining tests and write test report.
Should I write to a status file and write a function that checks it?

`@pytest.mark.skipif(setup_failed(), reason="requirements failed")`

[pytest-skipif-reference](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-mark-skip-ref)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really look at pytest-dependency plugin: https://pytest-dependency.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.dependency()
def test_b():
    pass
    
@pytest.mark.dependency(depends=["test_b"])
def test_d():
    pass
```

in this example `test_d` won't be executed if `test_b` fails

Comment: This will be perfect if I can get it to work on a session based fixture

Comment: hmm...will this solution help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671567/dependencies-between-files-with-pytest-dependency

Answer (score 4):

from the docs: http://pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#stopping-after-the-first-or-n-failures

```
pytest -x            # stop after first failure
pytest --maxfail=2    # stop after two failures
```

Comment: This case have around 50 tests, but only the first 5-6 test requirements and should skip everything if any fails. but the rest are independent and should be completed.

Answer (score 0):

I found that calling `pytest.exit("error message")` if any of my critical predefine tests fail is the most convenient. pytest will finish all post jobs like html-report, screenshots and your error message will be printed at the end:

```
!!!!!!!!!!! _pytest.outcomes.Exit: Critical Error: wips frontend in test1 not running !!!!!!!!!!!
===================== 1 failed, 8 passed in 92.72 seconds ======================
```