# Can't make pytest dependency work for different modules

Tags: python, dependencies, pytest, pytest-dependency, pytest-order

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50624303/913098) and [the doc](https://pytest-dependency.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scope.html), I am trying to make tests depend on each other between files:

`test_connectivity.py`:

```
@pytest.mark.dependency(depends=["test_services_up.py::test_sssss"], scope="session")
def test_aaa():
    assert False


@pytest.mark.dependency(depends=["tests/test_services_up.py::test_sssss"], scope="session")
def test_bbb():
    assert False

@pytest.mark.dependency(depends=["atp/tests/test_services_up.py::test_sssss"], scope="session")
def test_ccc():
    assert False
```

and `test_services_up.py`:

```
@pytest.mark.dependency()
def test_sssss():
    assert True
```

The folder structure:

```
    atp
    ----|tests
    --------|test_connectivity.py
    --------|test_services_up.py
```

Output:

```
> ssh://me@host:port~/src/uv-fleet-atp/venv/bin/python -u ~/.pycharm_helpers/pycharm/_jb_pytest_runner.py --path ~/src/uv-fleet-atp/atp/tests
============================= test session starts ==============================
collected 4 items                                                              

test_connectivity.py::test_aaa SKIPPED (test_aaa depends on test_ser...)
Skipped: test_aaa depends on test_services_up.py::test_sssss

test_connectivity.py::test_bbb SKIPPED (test_bbb depends on tests/te...)
Skipped: test_bbb depends on tests/test_services_up.py::test_sssss

test_connectivity.py::test_ccc SKIPPED (test_ccc depends on atp/test...)
Skipped: test_ccc depends on atp/tests/test_services_up.py::test_sssss

test_services_up.py::test_sssss PASSED


========================= 1 passed, 3 skipped in 0.35s =========================
```

How to not skip dependent tests?

Comment: The problem is the order of the tests. `pytest-dependency` does not order the tests, but if you install the `pytest-order` plugin and use the `order-dependencies` flag, the tests will be ordered so that tests that other tests depend on are run first.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Please explain. What's the point of dependency without order? This doesn't really make sense. Can you add code to show what you mean please?

Comment: Also, clearly at least 2 of these tests don't exist, yet there isn't even a warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `pytest-dependency` does not order tests, it relies on the tests executed in the correct order for dependencies to work. The reasoning behind this is that `pytest-dependency` is thought to do one thing and one thing only, which is to skip tests depending on the test relationships. Ordering can either be done manually by arranging the tests accordingly (e.g. adapt the names, what most users seem to do), or rely on an ordering plugin. There has been a controversial discussion about this, and certainly not everyone agrees with that philosophy (I tend to agree), but in the end it is the prerogative of the plugin author to decide.

[pytest-order](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-order/) works together with `pytest-dependency`. If it is installed and you run your tests with the option [--order-dependencies](https://pytest-dev.github.io/pytest-order/stable/configuration.html#order-dependencies) it will order your tests with `dependency` markers if needed. As usual, you can instead add the option to `pytest.ini`:

```
[pytest]
; always order tests with dependency markers
addopts = --order-dependencies
```

As for tests that cannot be found, it should issue a respective warning.

*Disclaimer:*
I'm the maintainer of `pytest-order`.

Comment: Thanks! So I did `pip install pytest-order` and `pytest_plugins = ["dependency", "order"]`. Getting `ImportError: Error importing plugin "order": No module named 'order'`

Comment: No need to add this to `pytest-plugins`, though I will have a look at this - probably using `pytest-order` instead of `order` will work.

Comment: Without adding, it works. With adding as `pytest-order`, still doesn't. Thanks!

Comment: Also, how do people order their tests without the plugin? alphabetically is so error prone...

Comment: Ok, it should read `pytest_order` instead, but that is obviously not documented... After a quick survey of other pytest plugins it turns out that most seem to use this (`pytest_xxx`) as entry point, so I'll probably keep it, but add it to the documentation.

Comment: Added a pytest-order SO tag you may want to watch

Comment: Does ordering also work with xdist to prevent race conditions?

Comment: Not really, see the [documentation](https://pytest-dev.github.io/pytest-order/stable/other_plugins.html#usage-with-pytest-xdist)

Comment: I am trying to run a single test with this usage, but if it depends on another test, it just doesn't run, instead of first calling that test. Can this be worked around? I don't want to have to run the entire suite every time

Comment: I don't know of a feature or plugin that does that, and it is probably not trivial to write one, as it would involve calling a test that is not loaded yet. Sorry, no idea at the moment... And thanks for the tag, BTW - I'm watching it now.

Comment: Why does it require to calling a not loaded test? Don't all tests get loaded, then some get skipped by static information?

Comment: I meant loaded in the sense of processed by pytest, so that it will be available in the pytest hooks. You may ask a separate question regarding this, there are certainly more knowledgeable folks out there.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but after while I found pytest-depends plugin, which is close similar to the dependency plugin but the main difference is 'depends' works as you want.
So If you have all tests in one direction but the dependency is only on test files then you can try with:

```
@pytest.mark.depends(on=["test_services_up.py::test_sssss"], scope="session")
def test_aaa():
    assert False


@pytest.mark.depends(on=["test_services_up.py::test_sssss"], scope="session")
def test_bbb():
    assert False

@pytest.mark.depends(on=["test_services_up.py::test_sssss"], scope="session")
def test_ccc():
    assert False


test_services_up.py
@pytest.mark.depends()
def test_sssss():
    assert True
```

This should help and work, 'depends' plugin has also auto order, which means that it will run firstly main tests.
You can find more here:
https://pypi.org/project/pytest-depends/