# How to control the incremental test case in Pytest

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest

```
@pytest.mark.incremental
class Test_aws():

    def test_case1(self):
        ----- some code here ----
        result = someMethodTogetResult
        assert result[0] == True
        orderID = result[1]

    def test_case2(self):
        result = someMethodTogetResult # can be only perform once test case 1 run successfully.
        assert result == True

    def test_deleteOrder_R53HostZonePrivate(self):
        result = someMethodTogetResult
        assert result[0] == True
```

The current behavior is if test 1 passes then test 2 runs and if test 2 passes then test 3 runs.

What I need is:
If test_case 3 should be run if test_case 1 passed. test_case 2 should not change any behavior. Any thoughts here?

Comment: Perhaps it is too simple, but why not move `test_case2() `just to a separate class? Tests are meant to be easily readable and convoluted logic makes tham harder to understand/reproduce.

Comment: Also these two test classes can ingerit from the same base if you want to share `someMethodTogetResult` method.

Comment: Test case 2 can't be executed until one is performed

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak some third party api from aws

Comment: Makes a good case for unbundling the test cases - it is a bad practice for tests not to be able to run in isolation - perhaps make a fixture that makes an independent input for testcase_2

Comment: Here we have some test case that depend on third party actual api not just mock. Say test case 1 create a EC2 instance on AWS, test case 2 Stop that instance and test case 3 delete the instance. So even if test case 2 failed we can delete inctance without stop it.

Comment: Now it is more clear what you are doing, I can see you intent of saving time of creating a new EC2 instance for each test. It probably makes a good separate question, eg Share same setup for integration test, I'd love to see a better approach for it myself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you are looking for [`pytest-dependency`](http://pytest-dependency.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which allows setting conditional run dependencies between tests. Example:

```
import random
import pytest


class TestAWS:

    @pytest.mark.dependency
    def test_instance_start(self):
        assert random.choice((True, False))

    @pytest.mark.dependency(depends=['TestAWS::test_instance_start'])
    def test_instance_stop(self):
        assert random.choice((True, False))

    @pytest.mark.dependency(depends=['TestAWS::test_instance_start'])
    def test_instance_delete(self):
        assert random.choice((True, False))
```

`test_instance_stop` and `test_instance_delete` will run only if `test_instance_start` succeeds and skip otherwise. However, since `test_instance_delete` does not depend on `test_instance_stop`, the former will execute no matter what the result of the latter test is. Run the example test class several times to verify the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

To complement [hoefling's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50590424/7262247), another option is to use [pytest-steps](https://smarie.github.io/python-pytest-steps/) to perform incremental testing. This can help you in particular if you wish to share some kind of incremental state/intermediate results between the steps.

However it does not implement advanced dependency mechanisms like `pytest-dependency`, so use the package that better suits your goal.

With pytest-steps, hoefling's example would write:

```
import random
from pytest_steps import test_steps, depends_on

def step_instance_start():
    assert random.choice((True, False))

@depends_on(step_instance_start)
def step_instance_stop():
    assert random.choice((True, False))

@depends_on(step_instance_start)
def step_instance_delete():
    assert random.choice((True, False))

@test_steps(step_instance_start, step_instance_stop, step_instance_delete)
def test_suite(test_step):
    # Execute the step
    test_step()
```

EDIT: there is a new 'generator' mode to make it even easier:

```
import random
from pytest_steps import test_steps, optional_step

@test_steps('step_instance_start', 'step_instance_stop', 'step_instance_delete')
def test_suite():
    # First step (Start)
    assert random.choice((True, False))
    yield

    # Second step (Stop)
    with optional_step('step_instance_stop') as stop_step:
        assert random.choice((True, False))
    yield stop_step

    # Third step (Delete)
    with optional_step('step_instance_delete') as delete_step:
        assert random.choice((True, False))
    yield delete_step
```

Check the [documentation](https://smarie.github.io/python-pytest-steps/) for details. (I'm the author of this package by the way ;) )

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pytest-ordering](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-ordering/) package to order your tests using pytest mark. The author of the package explains the usage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22468705/)

Example:

```
@pytest.mark.first
def test_first():
    pass

@pytest.mark.second
def test_2():
    pass


@pytest.mark.order5
def test_5():
    pass
```