# Interleaved repeat of pytest

Tags: pytest

I have some tests which I would like to repeat a number of times. I tried the pytest-repeat plugin

```
pip3 install pytest-repeat

import pytest
@pytest.mark.repeat(2)
class TestDemo():
    def test_demo1(self):
        pass
    def test_demo2(self):
        pass
```

This works

```
test_class_repeat.py::TestDemo::test_demo1[1/2] PASSED
test_class_repeat.py::TestDemo::test_demo1[2/2] PASSED
test_class_repeat.py::TestDemo::test_demo2[1/2] PASSED
test_class_repeat.py::TestDemo::test_demo2[2/2] PASSED
```

Except that I want an interleaved order running all tests, and the run all tests again

```
test_class_repeat.py::TestDemo::test_demo1[1/2] PASSED
test_class_repeat.py::TestDemo::test_demo2[1/2] PASSED
test_class_repeat.py::TestDemo::test_demo1[2/2] PASSED
test_class_repeat.py::TestDemo::test_demo2[2/2] PASSED
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pytest - test flow order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51539570/pytest-test-flow-order)

Answer (score 0):

Well, not a very clean solution, naively just define a test function that executes the interleaved tests while skipping the definition itself, and apply repeat on that:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.skip(reason='Definition only')
class TestDemo():
    def test_demo1(self):
        print('In Test 1')
        assert 1 == 1
    def test_demo2(self):
        print('In Test 2')
        assert 2 == 2


@pytest.mark.repeat(2)
def test_all():
    demo = TestDemo()
    demo.test_demo1()
    demo.test_demo2()
```

Execution (in jupyter notebook) gives:

```
Test.py::TestDemo::test_demo1 SKIPPED
Test.py::TestDemo::test_demo2 SKIPPED
Test.py::test_all[1/2] 
In Test 1
In Test 2
PASSED
TestProject.py::test_all[2/2] 
In Test 1
In Test 2
PASSED
```

Side note: if one of the two nested tests does not pass `test_all` does not pass, something desired from interleaved tests?

Comment: This unfortunately does not report test_demo1 and test_demo2 individually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pytest-flakefinder](https://github.com/dropbox/pytest-flakefinder) package by dropbox. It repeats tests after the run is complete.

Usage: `py.test --flake-finder --flake-runs=runs`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the pytest.mark.parametrize if the functions have a parameter. Below is an example.

```
import pytest
iter_list = [1,2,3]
@pytest.mark.parametrize('param1', iter_list, scope = 'class')
class TestDemo():
    def test_demo1(self, param1):
        pass
    def test_demo2(self, param1):
        pass
```