# pytest execute certain tests before executing a particular test

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest

consider an example where I have 3 tests

```
def test_a():
   pass

def test_b():
   pass

def test_c():
   pass
```

now there is a plugin 'dependency' which creates execution dependency. But this is not what I am looking for. What I am trying to achieve is following

```
def test_a():
   pass

def test_b():
   pass

@pytest...[ some way to say that always execute test_a and test_b before 
            executing test_c ]
def test_c():
   pass
```

with this i can always have test_a and test_b executed even if i e.g. I invoke pytest as following

```
pytest -k test_c
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17571438/2988730. The plugin you are referring to was written as a result of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22468705/2988730

Comment: @MadPhysicist this is not what I am looking for. I want to mandate execution of test_a and test_b if pytest chooses (based on various parameters) to run test_c. I tried the plugin and it does not do that.

Comment: I am not claiming that it is a duplicate by any means, just that it is tangentially related to your question. I'm very curious about how to solve this too, but reading the other question leads me to believe that you would have to implement the equivalent of portions of that plugin.

Comment: Sorry didn't want to be rude, apologies. The plugin you suggested is very close to what i am asking. may be a new parameter to tweak it.

Comment: No worries, I did not take your comment as rudeness at all. I also just realized that pytest-order is not what you want. pytest-dependency is in fact the way to go. It may be a little more complicated than your requirements, but you will have to implement something similar from scratch if you want to get similar functionality.