# How to specify test execution order using custom marker

Tags: python, pytest

I have set/aggregation of tests, I need to run these group of tests in certain order(this is not to manage dependency but for business reasons). How can I specify test execution order using marker?
I can not use command line options.

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.webtest
def test_send_http():
    pass # perform some webtest test for your app

@pytest.mark.webtest
def test_send_mail():
    pass # perform some webtest test for your app

@pytest.mark.config
def test_something_quick():
    pass

@pytest.mark.ui
def test_something_quick():
    pass
```

I need to run config, webtest and then UI test. Also, how can you know that each group finished executing?

Is there any other way to achieve this behavior?
Thank you

Comment: Did you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571438/test-case-execution-order-in-pytest?

Comment: yes, I am trying to avoid adding dependency just for ordering test execution.

Comment: Then implement your own ordering via custom `pytest_collection_modifyitems` hook impl.