# Run slow Pytest commands at the end of the test suite

Tags: python, pytest

Let's say I have the following pytest script:

```
import pytest

def test_one():
    pass

def test_two():
    pass

@pytest.mark.slow
def test_three():
    pass
```

Is there a single command I can use to run all tests with the `slow` marker last? I know I can do this using two pytest commands but it would be great to do this using a single command:

```
pytest -v -m "not slow"
# test_markers.py::test_one PASSED                                                                                                                    
# test_markers.py::test_two PASSED

pytest -v -m slow
# test_markers.py::test_three PASSED
```

Comment: does the [`pytest-ordering`](https://pytest-ordering.readthedocs.io/en/develop/) plugin fit your needs

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add custom sorting of collected tests and place the items with the `slow` marker last. Put the following code in a file `conftest.py` in your project or test root dir:

```
from _pytest.mark import Mark


empty_mark = Mark('', [], {})


def by_slow_marker(item):
    return item.get_closest_marker('slow', default=empty_mark)


def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items):
    items.sort(key=by_slow_marker, reverse=False)
```

This will place the items having the `slow` marker at the end of the collected tests sequence. If you want to turn this functionality on and off, add a custom command line flag:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--slow-last', action='store_true', default=False)


def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items, config):
    if config.getoption('--slow-last'):
        items.sort(key=by_slow_marker, reverse=True)
```

Running `pytest --slow-last` will now resort the items.

Comment: Works great! Just need to remove `reverse=True` to get the slow tests to run last.

Comment: I had to change `by_slow_marker` to `return 1 if item.get_closest_marker('slow') is None else 0` to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

As of Python 3.11, the 1st answer's original code did not work for me (functions parameters were not valid any more), here is an updated version...

```python
def by_slow_marker(item):
    return 0 if item.get_closest_marker("slow") is None else 1

def pytest_collection_modifyitems(session, config, items):
    if config.getoption("--slow-last"):
        items.sort(key=by_slow_marker, reverse=False)

def pytest_addoption(parser, pluginmanager):
    parser.addoption("--slow-last", action="store_true", default=False)
```