# What is most effective method to execute test cases written in pytests?

Tags: python, automated-tests, pytest

Let's consider there are 100's of tests written in multiple test{N}.py files (some of the dependant of each other and hooked dependencies).

```
   pages
   |--page1.py
   |--page2.py
   tests
   |--config.py
   |--test1.py
   |--test2.py
   |--test3.py 
   run_all_tests.py
   drivers
```

Following the POM model. All test cases are appended in the run_all_tests.py.

**Question 1**. Every time when need to skip tests from execution, I skip those from test1.py, test2.py, test3.py, etc files with a marker. Is there any effective way to do so without touching test files?

**Question 2** Can we execute test cases in sequence by providing sequence/execution order in the run_all_tests.py? (Like in TestNG one can execute from .xml file, can provide an order of execution and skip tests etc. features)

Comment: What do you mean by "POM model"? You don't need a file `run_all_tests.py`, the command `pytest` will automatically discover tests if their modules start with `test_`.

Comment: Question 1: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html `--ignore=tests/foobar/test_foobar_03.py --ignore=tests/hello/` Question 2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571438/test-case-execution-order-in-pytest