# Pytest ordering of test suites

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pytest

I've a set of test files (.py files) for different UI tests.
I want to run these test files using pytest in a specific order. I used the below command

```
python -m pytest -vv -s --capture=tee-sys --html=report.html --self-contained-html ./Tests/test_transTypes.py ./Tests/test_agentBank.py ./Tests/test_bankacct.py
```

The pytest execution is triggered from an AWS Batch job.
When the test executions happens it is not executing the test files in the order as specified in the above command.
Instead it first runs test_agentBank.py followed by test_bankacct.py, then test_transTypes.py
Each of these python files contains bunch of test functions.

I also tried decorating the test function class such as @pytest.mark.run(order=1) in the first python file(test_transTypes.py), @pytest.mark.run(order=2) in the 2nd python file(test_agentBank.py) etc.
This seems to run the test in the order, but at the end I get a warning

```
 PytestUnknownMarkWarning: Unknown pytest.mark.run - is this a typo?  You can register custom marks to avoid this warning - for details, see https://docs
.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/mark.html
    @pytest.mark.run(order=1)
```

What is the correct way of running tests in a specific order in pytest?
Each of my "test_" python files are the ones I need to run using pytest.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you care about the order? Generally speaking, tests should be independent.

Comment: @pL3b is right. You could refer a sample code at https://stackoverflow.com/a/77755875/294577

Comment: even if tests are (as they should be) independent, imagine using xdist to parallelize the tests running, and then if a few tests are significantly longer running than all the other ones, unless they ran first your parallelization may typically not yield as much time saving on average ― not with the current options that xdist sports ― ordering them by a-prior knowledge of their average runtime can bring about great gains in aggregate elapsed time under a parallel run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To specify the order in which tests are run in pytest, you can use the [pytest-order](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-order/) plugin. This plugin allows you to customize the order in which your tests are run by providing the `order` marker, which has attributes that define when your tests should run in relation to each other. You can use absolute attributes (e.g., first, second-to-last) or relative attributes (e.g., run this test before this other test) to specify the order of your tests. Here's an example:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.order(2)
def test_foo():
    assert True

@pytest.mark.order(1)
def test_bar():
    assert True
```

Answer (score 3):

> What is the correct way of running tests in a specific order in pytest? Each of my "test_" python files are the ones I need to run using pytest.

Answer to your question is using pytest hooks. You can read about hooks [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/writing_hook_functions.html#writing-hook-functions).

Basically you need to declare a method with specific signature in your `conftest.py` file. List of hooks that can be defined is stored [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#hooks).

In your specific case you need a hook named `pytest_collection_modifyitems`. You can find description of it [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_collection_modifyitems). You will be able to change order of elements in `items` list which is actually list of all collected tests.

So in your `conftest.py` it will look like this:

```
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(session, config, items):
   # some code that changing order of elements in items list
```

Comment: Also keep in mind that if you want to completely redefine `items` list (not just changing list that is being stored in `items` variable) you should use following syntax: `items[:] = ...`

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming them as `test_1_transTypes.py`, `test_2_agentBank.py` and `test_3_bankacct.py`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I did rename the files and ran the tests in this order. test_8_pmt.py, test_9_pmt.py, test_10_pmt.py. When I checked in Pycharm terminal it ran in the same order I specified. But the html report is not in the same order. It shows the results of test_9_pmt.py first, followed by test_8_pmt.py, finally test_10_pmt.py. I even tried sorting using "Test" column but no luck. Is there a way to see the report for the tests in exactly the same order that they ran? Thanks