# Python unittest/pytest tests priority

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest

i have many unittests in my project each independent from another, however i would like to run the tests in parallel on several cores and in order to get the most out of it, it's necessary that the longest tests run as early as possible.
Is it possible to give a priority order to the tests? something like

```
class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):

   @unittest.priority(2)
   def test_high_priority(self):

   @unittest.priority(1)
   def test_medium_priority(self):

   @unittest.priority(0)
   def test_low_priority(self):

   def test_low_priority2(self):
```

Many thanks

Comment: Try https://pypi.org/project/pytest-order/.

Comment: There are also some ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571438/how-to-control-test-case-execution-order-in-pytest) that might help you out.